# Identifying Motherboard Components

Tags: identification, components

I would like to know if it is possible to visually identify circled components of old G5 Apple Motherboard. Keyword search of the number written on the component is not useful in identification of the part.

[image]

Comment: If that's you putting thermal paste on there, its *way too much*. Most likely those are inductors [like this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/eaton---electronics-division/HCMA0703-R15-R/283-4540-1-ND/5168190?utm_adgroup=General&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Dynamic%20Search_RLSA_Cart&utm_term=&utm_content=General&gclid=CjwKCAjwte71BRBCEiwAU_V9h6gypfA5RLiixdwQhsWiCelVJnnztXb0J1HeMN53wWHszv216WdbjRoCSOMQAvD_BwE).

Comment: +1 for added advice. No thats not me, I googled the picture online cause I was bit lazy to take the picture of the card myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than that they are 0.15uH and 0.36uH inductors, their rated current and manufacturer can't be guessed from the photo.

Comment: Allright thanks a lot!